# Start default search activity without the SearchView

Tags: android, search, searchview

I am implementing the search widget http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget The search widget provides the same functionality as the search dialog. It starts the appropriate activity when the user executes a search, and it can provide search suggestions and perform voice search.

Everything works fine, I want to start the searchActivity without using the search widget and get the same result when clicking on one of the items bellow, how can I achieve that?

http://screencloud.net//img/screenshots/9b2638fbf1dd928abed678f9d3081479.png

So when I click lounge / nightclub it does the same as when I use the searchWidget(Restaurant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start your search activity yourself like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "some text");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Where `SearchActivity` is your activity implementing

Comment: yeah that's kind of right currently I am doing 
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH); 
 intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "Heiko"); 
 startActivity(intent); 
But that brings an option of all the apps that have implemented such  Activity, and I want to skip that and use mine by default

Comment: I want to use the Intent.ACTION_SEARCH

Comment: If you want to skip the chooser dialog, you have to give it a package and class to use. Why do you want to use ACTION_SEARCH if you already know what activity you want to start?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH);
                            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class));
                            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "some text");
                            startActivity(intent);